# Why is AsyncTask working on the main thread?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use `AsyncTask` to do a task in the background and then present it when it is done, but what happens is that nothing is displayed until it is done.

I also tried to use execute and `doInBackground` to call it, but both cause the same issue and I have to wait for the activity to start with everything ready rather than show a page with the loading progress bar and then add the list later.

**Code:**

```
private class listTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        recyclerview.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getInternalFileList()));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    List<GalleryItem> getInternalFileList(){
        String path = getActivity().getFilesDir().toString();
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        List<GalleryItem> galleryItems = new ArrayList<>();

        MainDBRepository repo = new MainDBRepository(getActivity());
        HashMap<String,GalleryItem> itemsMap = repo.getItemsMap();

        for(File file : files) {
            if(itemsMap.containsKey(file.getName()))
                galleryItems.add(itemsMap.get(file.getName()));
        }

        Collections.reverse(galleryItems);

        return galleryItems;
    }

    private class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mItemImageView;

        ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mItemImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        }

        public void bindBackgroundImage(Bitmap backgroundImage){
            mItemImageView.setImageBitmap(backgroundImage);
        }

        public void bindImageViewer(final String path){
            mItemImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = ImageViewerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), path);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder> {
        private List<GalleryItem> galleryItems;

        ItemAdapter(List<GalleryItem> galleryItems) {
            galleryItems = galleryItems;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new ItemHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder itemHolder, int position) {
            GalleryItem galleryItem = galleryitems.get(position);
            String path = getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + galleryItem.getID();
            File file = new File(path);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            itemHolder.bindBackgroundImage(bitmap);
            itemHolder.bindImageViewer(path);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return galleryitems.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asynctask works on main thread itself. It is created to run on main thread.

Comment: If you want to show something while the `AsyncTask` is computing you should implement the `onProgressUpdate(Progress... values)` method which is called from `publishProgress(Progress... values)` and implements the logic under the background task progress.

Comment: Please show how you call your async task. You are not using `.get()` on it are you?

Comment: No, new listTask().execute() and also tried new listTask().doInBackground()

Comment: The first call is ok. The second one is forbidden. Never do that!

Comment: `what happens is that nothing is displayed until the it is done.`. It is unclear what you want to be displayed. Well except for that progressbar.

Comment: I want the fragment (with the progressbar) to be displayed, while the asynctask is working, what is currently happening is that the app would freeze until the whole fragment is done (including all of the asynctask)

Comment: `(ItemAdapter(getInternalFileList())`?? That is a very strange instantiation.   I would expect you to use something like `(new ItemAdapter(getInternalFileList())`.

Comment: Further you better only get the files list in doInBackground() and create and set the adapter in onPostExecute().

Comment: You still did not tell what should be displayed meanwhile. A fragment? Which views would it have? Please tell what the user would see.

Comment: weird, I have it as new ItemAdapter in the code but looks like i removed it while pasting and doing minor changes, also tried your suggestion, while it did start the fragment, it froze once it got to the onPostExecute, so the progressbar was visible but frozen. Thank you

Comment: The user would see a fragment, with a progressbar rotating, until it is done and the progress bar is removed and list is filled.

Comment: Fragment are invisible unless they contain views. So what does the user see?

Comment: Make the progressbar a member of the asynctask class and instantiate in onPreExecute().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to show something in the UI while the `AsyncTask` is computing the background task you should implement the onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) method which is called from `publishProgress(Progress... values)` and implements the logic under the background task progress. In your code you just show the final result in the `onPostExecute()`. Note that the `AsyncTask` run the `doInBackground()` method in a different thread than the UI thread and `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()` on the UI thread because they should update UI. For more info refer to the Android Doc [about AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not sure if I got your right, but what I meant is that, the fragment itself doesn't load before the asynctask finishes, the fragment has a progressbar by default that i want displayed first before the asynctask finishes, what happens is the screen freezes and I have to wait for the fragment to appear with everything loaded. Shouldn't using asynctask let me load the fragment before it finishes?

Comment: Fragments have their own lifecycle so you just have to implement their `onSomething()` methods to load the UI part correctly. `AsyncTask`s are used when you have to do something "heavy" (takes a lot of time) in the background avoiding the UI to freez (not responding to user input). I don't think using an `AsyncTask` is the correct way for your problem.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding Asynctask, will try to reread the documentation again, maybe I will find my problem, thank you

Comment: Well go on. Eight!

Comment: Can anybody explain me why this irre!evant not to the point answer got so many upvotes?

Answer (score 5):

On the background just means - not on the UI - thread. To get results before the job is finished you will need to feed results to the UI thread while doing the job on the background. To get results on the UI thread before you can use AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate(..) - or better use kotlin coroutines instead of asynctask.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not sure if I got your right, but what I meant is that, the fragment itself doesn't load before the asynctask finishes, the fragment has a progressbar by default that i want displayed first before the asynctask finishes, what happens is the screen freezes and I have to wait for the fragment to appear with everything loaded. Shouldn't using asynctask let me load the fragment before it finishes?